# WampServer orange icon Apache Not Started

Tags: php, apache, server, wamp

I am having problems with WAMP Server, the icon will never turn green. It is constantly stuck at orange, where apache isn't.

I tried the following in the menu

- Apache
- Service
- Test port 80

It showed the following:

> Your port 80 is actually used by : Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.5.

Comment: This is port conflict.Just modify the apache's(or IIS's port) port to other port. For Apache: find httpd.conf,then change "Listen 80" to "Listen 8080" . Remember to **restart the Apache service**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by disabling the IIS Service:

1. Computer
2. manage
3. Service and Application
4. Service
5. world wibe publishing
6. Right Click
7. Stop

Then Start Apache and WAMP goeas already green.

Comment: Unfortunately that service will probably restart when you reboot and everytime you reboot. If youare not using IIS uninstall it and anything else that uses port 80. One webserver per PC is the best.